# should I use memory fences in a supervisor-workers model?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, memory-fences

I am building multithreading support for my application.

In my application, it can happen that a worker should access the "work field" of another worker to complete its own job. I have tried to make this safe with pthread mutexes, but they turned out to be horribly slow, even when there is only one worker and no so contention.

So, I came up with another idea. Let a worker complete its job where it can, and then add to a (per-worker, own) queue the jobs that have the aforementioned problem: when all the workers are done, the main supervisor thread will complete the unfinished jobs, in the hope that they will be orders of magnitude fewer than the number of jobs got done by the workers.

My question is: should I throw in a memory fence, at the moment that I transfer the execution from the supervisor to the workers and vice-versa?

EDIT:
more details (the code is on [github](https://github.com/pisto/laurea/blob/master/pool.cpp), see pool::collision_wsc()). Each thread reads pointers from various "cells" (which are basically a std::vector), and applies some operation on the objects pointed (collision between hard spheres).

The point is that a cell interacts with (some of) its neighbours, but some of these cells might be in the ownership of another worker (one sphere might be near the bounds of a cell, and collide with one of another cell).

Comment: Need more details. Getting threading right requires knowing the entire system.

Comment: @usr then ask something specific, because I don't really know what other info you need. If you are really up to some gory details, the code is on github, the functions that I'm trying to parallelize are pool::timestep and pool::collision_wsc https://github.com/pisto/laurea/blob/master/pool.cpp

Comment: @usr some more details in the question.